# Is it possible to make sap.m.MultiInput always in multi line mode?

Tags: sapui5

Currently this control will present multi line mode when you focus in(when set to true enableMultiLineMode firstly). when you focus out of the multi line mode is disabled. I also found a prototype method "openMultiLine", but when I call it that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Either override the MultiInput.onsapfocusleave event or just make it undefined, like so:

```
oMultiInput.openMultiLine();    
oMultiInput.onsapfocusleave = undefined;
```